# MySQL throwing exception while open the connection

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, exception, web-hosting

I am receiving following exception on hosted website for a days ago while its have been running fine for years. I searched the internet with the exception and added the following in web.config

```
 <trust level="Medium"/>
```

and

```
<trust level="Full"/>
```

under  but not resolved my problem.

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1085.0

My connection string is as following:

```
<add name="conMysql" connectionString="server=localhost;database=db1;uid=myuser;password=pass;Charset=utf8;" />
```

### Following is the Exception page:

```html
<html><head>
        <title>Security Exception</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><h1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width="100%" size="1" color="silver"></h1>

            <h2> <i>Security Exception</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy. &nbsp;To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.
            <br><br>

            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.SocketPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.<br><br>

            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

            <table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tbody><tr>
                  <td>
                      <code>

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody></table>

            <br>

            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

            <table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tbody><tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.SocketPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark) +34
   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +46
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.CheckCacheRemote(EndPoint&amp; remoteEP, Boolean isOverwrite) +168
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean flowContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +6607720
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +233
   MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.CreateSocketStream(IPAddress ip, Boolean unix) +165
   MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(UInt32 timeout) +347
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() +171
</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody></table>

            <br>

            <hr width="100%" size="1" color="silver">

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1085.0

            </font>

    

</body></html>
```

Here's the exception with the html removed.

Security Exception

Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy. To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.SocketPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Source Error:
             An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
         [SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.SocketPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark&amp; stackMark) +34
   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +46
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.CheckCacheRemote(EndPoint&amp; remoteEP, Boolean isOverwrite) +168
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean flowContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +6607720
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +233
   MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.CreateSocketStream(IPAddress ip, Boolean unix) +165
   MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(UInt32 timeout) +347
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() +171
```

Comment: Do you control this server? If not, have you contacted the tech support department of the people who do control it? Is it operated by a hosting service?

Comment: @OllieJones, I am not hosting the server, I didn't contact the support, actually they are not cooperative enough. that's why I am considering to even move to some other hosting company.